# HTML5 video tag : Can't use relative height and properly place Controls

Tags: html, css, reactjs, controls, html5-video

Using [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs), I'm inserting a video in a component but it doesn't seems to like when I use a relative unit in the `max-height` I've set for the container.

And I'd **like to use `vh` to set the `max-height`**, but when I do the video **goes above the other contents** of the page (like a wild `z-index`) and don't work like a child-block that'd set the container's dimensions...

**Is it possible to counter/avoid that effect?**

---

Simplified render method :

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className='ThatComponentContainer'>
      <div>
        <p>Some content</p>
      </div>
      <div className='VideoPlayer'  width='520' height='294'>
        <video controls preload="auto" width='520' height='294'>
          <source src={VideoWEBM} type="video/webm" />
          <p>I'm sorry; your browser doesn't support HTML5 video in WebM with VP8/VP9 or MP4 with H.264.</p>
        </video>
      </div>
      <div>
        Some other cotent
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

CSS:

```
.ThatComponentContainer {
  display: flex;
 }

.VideoPlayer video {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto; 
}

.VideoPlayer {
  /* 
  max-height: 20vh;  <<<----- I'd like to use this */
  max-height: 588px;
  min-height: 294px;
  height: auto;

  max-width: 90%;
  width: auto;
}
```

---

Here is the video, and I've another issue but I can't seem to find anything about it...
The video's **controls are over the video's bottom**, hence you can't see a part of the video.
I'd like to have the **controls under the video, is it possible?**.

[image: Video screen capture]

Comment: Your css part is missing, [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/205we3ha/)

Comment: @NoopurDabhi : I don't get it, my CSS is both in the question and in the rendered website... What do you mean?

Comment: Check the fiddle I added in above comment, video is working properly.

Comment: Video controls are part of `shadow-dom`, currently there is no support for moving it outside of video component.

For your case, you can use custom skin for video player. Check out this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery/Video_player_styling_basics for more information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated by [Tushar Vaghela](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1385267/tushar-vaghela) in the comments, this is part of the `shadow-dom` (the built in browser CSS, essentially).

**The best solution right now is to hide controls and use simple custom ones.** Here's everything you need, courtesy of MDN.

- [The code](https://github.com/iandevlin/iandevlin.github.io/tree/master/mdn/video-player-styled)
- [Live example](https://iandevlin.github.io/mdn/video-player-styled/)
- [Written guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery/Video_player_styling_basics)

Answer (score 0):

try to add this css too with your video tag if it helps

```
video {
    object-fit: fill;
}
```

if this does not work for you than try video.js it will help you to give your video player a customs options too with the default controls

Comment: This didn't work for me, unfortunately. According the docs `object-fit` is designed to modify the overall video size for it's *container*, nothing related to controls.